# Проблема с отображение формы, созданной simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с бедой, прошу совета. Установил гем `simple_form` и создал с помощью него форму.

```
<%= simple_form_for @ad do |f| %>

<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :content %>
<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

При переходе на страницу с формой не отображается второе поле для ввода (первое нормально отображается). Уже перепробовал все, что только смог придумать мой маленький ум. Пробовал изменять и тип данных, которые в БД записываются с text на string. Проверял правильность ввода всех названий и переменных в модели, контроллере и вьюхе. Менял форму на стандартную, что идет искаропки. Ничего не помогло. Вторая строка не отображается. Точнее, после перезапуска браузера, она появляется на короткое время, а потом исчезает. Хотя в структуре HTML-документа присутствует в виде тега с параметрами и все такое, но визуально не отрисовывается.

Посоветуйте в какую сторону копать, а то как-то уже вата в голове, битый час сижу не могу настроить форму в этом приложении... =\

Буду благодарен за любые советы!

Comment: Если в HTML-документе тэг присутствует, нет ли вероятности того, что его скрывает какой-то JS/CSS-код? Посмотрите инспектором CSS-свойство display элемента? В нем какое значение?

Comment: display: block;

Comment: https://github.com/myacheg/adapp ссылка на приложение.

Comment: Вижу и текстовое поле, и текстовую область, прекрасно создаются новые объявления. Браузер FireFox. Правда чтобы запустить проект я bundle update сделал, что-то не заладилось у меня с вашим Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Это хорошо, что я написал рабочий код... Вот только почему-то он у меня не работает так как надо. =( Пробовал и  в хроме и в файрфоксе. Результат одинаковый. Ну что же.. Буду искать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблема простая и заключается в имени поля ввода. FireFox, почему-то, не хотел отображать поле с именем content. Помогло изменение имени, все стало отображаться коректно. Если что, версия FireFox for Ubuntu v45.0. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Нет, заключается проблема не в этом. Firefox 45 под Debian Jessie (LMDE2), всё прекрасно работает с `content`.